# how to set selected value of dropdownlist?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

My dropdown list clears after press submit button. i try to change but error occured.

```
<select name="staff" id="staff" required>
    <option value="">Select Staff</option>
    <?php while($row_subject = mysql_fetch_array($query_subject)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_subject['deo_code']; ($this->input->post('staff') == $row_subject['deo_code'] ? ' selected' : '') ?>">
    <?php echo $row_subject['deo_code']."-".$row_subject['deo_name'];?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Code. Input. Expected Output. Actual Output. Error messages and log entries. Mention these, and we have a question we might be able to answer!

Comment: It is absolutely unhelpful to only tell us _that_ an error occurred, without telling us what that error actually _was_. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You failed to close the `value` attribute properly with a `"` before you output `selected`, so it becomes _part of_ the value attribute, instead of being a stand-alone attribute.

Answer (score -1):

you can use some thing like this:

```
<select name="staff" id="staff" required>
    <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $i ?>" <?php $i == 2 ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?php echo $i ?< بزرگسال</option>
        <option value="">Select Staff</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please explain why your code works to help people who face a similar problem in the future

Comment: And associate your answer more closely to the code in the question. Just dumping an irrelevant code sample is not an answer

Comment: And it is normal to put the Que line `<option value="">Select Staff</option>` out as the first item in the dropdown